# How to send direct message to Twitter friend using iOS

Tags: ios, post, twitter

I want to send a direct message to a Twitter friend. I am using the following code (`appdelegate.twitterAccount` is a Twitter account from the iOS `ACAccountStore`):

```
AppDelegate *appdelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSString *idString = @"123456789"; // should be some read user_id
NSString *urlString = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json?";
NSURL *postDirectMessageRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"user_id": idString,
                             @"text": @"some text"};
SLRequest *postDirectMessageRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter 
                                                         requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
                                                                   URL:postDirectMessageRequestURL 
                                                            parameters:parameters];
postDirectMessageRequest.account = appdelegate.twitterAccount;
[postDirectMessageRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (nil != error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"urlResponse: %@", urlResponse);
    }
}];
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error, although the Twitter account is correctly set up in iOS:

```
Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey=<CFURLResponse 0x160352490 [0x19ebeb150]>{url = https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json?}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json?}
```

So, something is wrong with the authentication, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer (that is probably wrong, see below) to what went wrong is that an app logged in to Twitter by iOS does not have direct message permission, as seen in the „Apps“ settings of the Twitter account used:
[image]
Sorry for the German. It says read and write permission, i.e. no direct message permission.

I solved the problem using the Fabric and Twitter frameworks.
I downloaded the [Mac Fabric app](https://get.fabric.io/ios) that lets you install the Twitter framework easily. It even lets you copy and paste the basic code required.
I defined me a `Twitter_Helper` class that contains the following methods:

```
+(void)twitterInit {
    [Fabric with:@[[Twitter class]]]; // initialize Twitter
}

+(void)loginCompletion:(void(^)(TWTRSession *, NSError *))completionBlock_ {
    [[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithMethods:TWTRLoginMethodSystemAccounts | TWTRLoginMethodWebBased 
                                    completion:^(TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
        if (nil == session) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
        completionBlock_(session, error);
    }];
}

+(TWTRAPIClient *)getTwitterClientForCurrentSession {
    NSString *userID = [Twitter sharedInstance].sessionStore.session.userID;
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [[TWTRAPIClient alloc] initWithUserID:userID];
    return client;
}

+(void)loadFollowersOfUserWithId:(NSString *)userId completion:(void(^)(NSDictionary *, NSError *))completionBlock_ {
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [Twitter_Helper getTwitterClientForCurrentSession];
    NSString *loadFollowersEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"user_id" : userId};
    NSError *clientError;

    NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET" URL:loadFollowersEndpoint parameters:params error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            if (data) {
                NSDictionary *followersDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                                    error:nil];
                completionBlock_(followersDictionary, nil);
            }
            else {
                completionBlock_(nil, connectionError);
            }
        }];
    }
    else {
        completionBlock_(nil, clientError);
    }
}

+(void)sendDirectMessage:(NSString *)message toUserWithId:(NSString *)userId completion:(void(^)(NSError *))completionBlock_ {
    TWTRAPIClient *client = [Twitter_Helper getTwitterClientForCurrentSession];
    NSString *sendDirectMessageEndpoint = @"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json";
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"user_id" : userId,
                             @"text"    : message};
    NSError *clientError;

    NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URL:sendDirectMessageEndpoint parameters:params error:&clientError];

    if (request) {
        [client sendTwitterRequest:request completion:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
            completionBlock_(connectionError);
        }];
    }
    else {
        completionBlock_(clientError);
    }
}
```

When I want to send a direct message to a follower of a user (one can only send direct messages to followers), I log the user in using `loginCompletion:`, load the user’s follower ids by `loadFollowersOfUserWithId:completion:`, and then send the message by `sendDirectMessage:toUserWithId:completion:`.
This works without any problem.

Which I don’t understand is:
I first logged in using `TWTRLoginMethodWebBased`, since the [Twitter docs](https://docs.fabric.io/appledocs/Twitter/Constants/TWTRLoginMethod.html) say:
`TWTRLoginMethodSystemAccounts` *Attempts to log the user in with the system accounts. This log in method will only grant limited application permissions to the returned oauth token. If you would like to have more application permissions granted you must use the TWTRLoginMethodWebBased and configure your application correctly.*
`TWTRLoginMethodWebBased` *Presents a web view that allows the user to log in. This method will allow the developer to request more application permissions.*

However, when I logged in using `TWTRLoginMethodWebBased`, I did not have any opportunity to request direct message permission. This is the login screen:
[image]

It says that I won't have direct message permission, and when I looked up the app settings, the permission was indeed read and write only:
[image]
Even more strange is that I could also send direct messages when I logged in using `TWTRLoginMethodSystemAccounts`. Maybe direct message permission is only required for reading or deleting direct messages, but not for sending, but then I am back at my original question…